# How to pass Vim's regex captured groups to system command?

Tags: regex, vim, system

I have some data that looks like this:

```
6000.10c 1.2345E6
```

And I can write a regular expression for Vim to capture the 'important' parts:

```
/6000.10c\s\+\(\S\+\)
```

This will capture the number portion into the first group. What I would like to do is then pass this captured string to a system command that will do something with the results and return a string that is put into Vim.

**How do I send regex captured group(s) to a system command?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, well the awk is in fact not a must, it is just for showing the `system()`:

```
s/\v6000.10c\s+\zs(\S+)/\=system("awk '{print $0*2}' <<<". submatch(1))/
```

Will change:

```
6000.10c 1.2345E6
```

into:

```
6000.10c 2469000
```